# How to use Node.js to create a web scraper to fetch websites that need username/password and a captcha?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am currently using Node.js to do some market research. But I got stuck when I tried to log in on some websites that requires a username/password login. It also have a Captcha when login. Is there any detailed tutorial for this?

Thanks!

Comment: on how to bypass the required captcha ?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Thanks for your fast reply. Actually I can login it on my own and get a cookie, but by passing the cookie to the website it doesn't work. Maybe they added some protection. So if I want to directly access the website, I have to bypass the captcha and that is actually what I was asking for. Thanks!

Comment: different websites have different ways of securing against such methods, of course requiring Captcha is one (if not the only) of the common used ways because it simply works, and automating the process of auto-bypassing captchas won't work, even if you read the image using some kind of library or other program, the accuracy of that would be like 1 in a million (probably more).

It just looks pointless from my point of view.